# Show there's an analytic functions satisfying certain conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is analytic on $\{z: |z|<r\}$ for some $r>1$. Suppose further that $|f(z)|<1$ for $|z|=1$ and $f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2} $.

1) Find a set $U$ so that $f(0) \in U$ for every $f$ satisfying the condition and

2) show that for any $a \in U$ there exists an $f$ satisfying the conditions such that $f(0) = a$.

Thoughts so far: I think part 1) can be done using the Schwarz Lemma: For a biholomorphic map from the unit disk to the unit disk $g$ with $g(0) =\frac{1}{2}$ we have that $g^{-1}\circ f \circ g$ satisfies the conditions of the Lemma, so $(g^{-1}\circ f \circ g) (B_r) \subset B_r$, where $B_r$ is a open unit disk of radius $r<1$, centered at the origin. But I'm not sure how to finish this, and I'm unsure about how to approach problem 2). Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Looks like 2) is coming from 1), tacking U={f(0), where f satisfy conditions}. Are you sure about this problem?

Comment: From the maximum modulus principle, |f(0)| < 1.

Comment: @Eugen Covaci Do you think it follows directly? I got it from a previous qual, but it's possible they made a typo.